# Вывод текста в Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

Попытался вывести текст через

```
 Void OnGUI(){GUI.Label(new Rect(330, 120, 100, 20), count.ToString());}
```

Текст выводиться. Но Хотелось бы через UI, по новому, по красивому

в смотрел видео(офф.мануал Unity по UI text) https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-text

Там делается отдельный файл ScoreManager.cs
Там есть метод Awake.

Как мне поставить в это UI text свой текст из своего скрипта где метода Awake нет? Пробовал ставить код в метод Start, не выводит.

Comment: А как вы пытались? можно посмотреть код? И скрипт с данным кодом находится на каком объекте? На объекте UI text или на каком-то другом? .......и да...метод `Awake` вы всегда можете сами написать, вам никто не запрещает)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сейчас в Unity есть как минимум три стандартных способа вывода текста на экран:

- старый UI (то как вы указали через OnGUI())
- новый UI
- через TextMesh (лучше использовать, когда вам нужно выводить текст в игровом пространстве, а не через UI)

Если я верно понял вопрос, то вам нужен компонент Text в новом UI.
Тогда вариант для примера:

1. Добаляем в иерархии сцены новый UI->Text
2. В нужно скрипте добавляем поле public Text MyTestLabel;
3. Скрипт должен быть добавлен на какой-либо элемент в иерархии (например, какой-то контроллер сцены, или даже сам UI объект, это зависит от вашей архитектуры).
4. В инспекторе элемента сцены, к которому вы подлючили скрипт, перетаскиваем в появившееся поле элемент (через иерархию сцены)
5. Например в методе Start() добавляем строку MyTestLabel.text = "Hello world";

Положение на экране для компонента Text будет задаваться в редакторе.

Попробуйте в методе Start() добавить Debug.Log(название переменной, значение, которой вы хотите вывести);
Возможно, что в этот момент значение нужное не готово. Перенесите в Update, например. Посмотрите в нем, какое значение у переменной.

Кроме того, если скрипт наследуется от Monobehaviour класса, то все стандартные функции типо Start(), Update() и т.д. доступны для определения.

Comment: Оно не перетаскивается! 
Что делаю - создаю через меню GameObject->UI->Text, создаеться текстовая рамка с надписью внутри "New Text"
Затем создаю в скрипте  после MonoBehavior 
    public Text tt;
А в start()
tt.text = "testik";
В свойствах скрипта появляется место для перетаскивания,None(Text)всё окей. Но сам текст из иерархии туда не перетаскивается, просто запрещающий знак стоит.

Comment: Странно. Приложите скриншот. Звучит так, будто бы редактору не нравится тип перетаскиваемого элемента.

Comment: Альтернативно попробуйте (для временного теста) сделать переменную типа GameObject. А потом в методе private void Start() написать Debug.Log("равен ли объект null? " + название_вашей_переменной.gameobject.GetComponent<Text>() == null); и после этого в новое поле перенести ваш UI компонент. Если перенеслось, то запустить и проверить, что вывело в консоль.

Comment: `public class Snake2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text tt;
}
 void Start()
    {
        tt.text = "testik";
        InvokeRepeating("Move", 0.3f, 0.3f);

    }`

А скриншот [ссылка](http://savepic.ru/9991609.jpg), надеюсь, ничего не нарушил.

Comment: Кажется, я понял в чем дело. Скрипт нужно прикрепить к объекту на сцене. И уже тогда в инспекторе объекта сцены нужно перетаскивать элементы. Добавлю этот пункт на всякий случай в ответ тоже. Когда сам знаешь, что и как, то иногда тяжело описать все подробности, т.к. для самого очевидно. (ответ дополнил, надеюсь, стало яснее)

Answer (score 2):

Какой скрипт?
Нужно получить указатель на кнопки или их текст и тогда менять. Зависит от того как выглядит твой скрипт.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/ControllingGameObjectsComponents.html